# Any methods to cover yourself when dealing with smell during repair

Tags: smell

I was thinking of using a mask to cover my nose so that smell / smoke will not get into my nose while I am doing some repair work.

Beside using mask, are there better alternative such that I can still breathe normally? (The mask do make breathing quite difficult sometime. The worse case is using a oxygen tank but it seems to be a "over-kill" solution.)

Would appreciate if picture / illustration can be included.

Comment: What type of smoke?

Comment: What kind or repairs are you doing?

Comment: @shirlockhomes Actually some manual repair on my bike. Sometime can smell something. (Sometime, there is some white smoke - but it is the smell that I want to block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case a fully isolating mask connected to some source of fresh air is the best solution. Perhaps you could get without a tank and just have two pipes that end somewhere where there's no substance you protect from - not sure if it works, but worth considering.

The problem with the mask is it has pretty limited blocking capacity - if the substance has high concentration the mask filter will get saturated pretty soon and the mask will get ineffective. Add to this that it complicates breath and it's clear that the mask is not always the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post, but it came up in a search, so for future users -- Combine three things:

1. Use a fan to blow the smoke away from you. This is really the easiest, most common-sense thing you can do if you're in a garage or someplace with good windows
2. Use disposable masks to remove some of what remains (assuming you can't tolerate a mask made to block smoke entirely)
3. Use something to overwhelm the smell, since that's the primary goal in the posting

To cover up the smell, you could use vick's vapor rub on your upper lip like they do in morgues (at least, in tv shows/movies and in books).

Dealing with the horrific stench of tearing out urine soaked carpet, I happened to have a perfume oil from Kingsley that's a knockoff of "Spice Bomb" and I used that on my upper lip instead. It worked great, all I could smell was spices, and it lasted much longer than I expected.